# Get form attribute value with PHP

Tags: php, forms

Is there a way to get submitted form's attribute value using PHP, when the submit button is clicked?

I have a form which has attribute `data-id: someid`, I need to get this value.

Comment: you can achieve that by jquery

Comment: No, that is not directly possible - there is no reason for a browser to incorporate the content of an arbitrary HTML attribute into the form data set. You will have to put it into a hidden field or something like that first.

Comment: You cant HTML attribute to submitted data. U have to use Javascript

Comment: You can submit form by ajax, and recolect variables as your wish

Comment: only through javascript/jQuery form submission you can do that. Normal form submission will go with `name` attribute value only

Comment: One more possibility is create hidden filed with `name = 'data-id'` and add it's value like this:- `<input type="hidden" name="data-id" value="add value here">`. then through normal form submission also you will get that value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to get the data attribute value in PHP.
You have to first get data-attribute, set this value to hidden field and then use PHP to get it.

Answer (score 1):

If You Wants Data id on submit

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#formid').on('submit', function(){ 
    var id = $(this).data("id")
    alert(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <form action="" method="POST" name="myformName" id="formid" data-id="someid">
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in php with two ways:
1. Either pass your 'someid' in input with hidden type

```
<input type="hidden" name="data-id" value="someid" />
```

2. Just pass your 'someid' in action attribute

```
<form name="" action="filename.php?data-id=someid">
```